# upload captured image to cloudinary in android

Tags: android, camera, inputstream, image-uploading, cloudinary

> I want to upload a captured picture image cloudinary I have an error in this statment :

```
                cloudinary.uploader().upload(is, Cloudinary.emptyMap());
```

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
>
> I want to ask what should I pass at this to define the name of the pic
>
> first I get the the uri and convert it to string to get the path
>   then convert this real path to InputStream
>   so, I could pass it to the cloudinary uploading statement

```
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;
TextView tv;
String s="aa";
Map config = new HashMap();
Cloudinary cloudinary;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    config.put("cloud_name", "dkepfkeuu");
    config.put("api_key", "key");
    config.put("api_secret", "secret");
    cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
Bitmap photo;
InputStream is;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        s= data.getDataString();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Uri uripath= data.getData();
        String uri = getRealPathFromURI( uripath);
        try {
             is = new FileInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "uri:\n" +
                uri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tv.setText(s+"---"+uri);
        try {
            cloudinary.uploader().upload(is, Cloudinary.emptyMap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor =getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Note that your `api_secret` should never be revealed to anyone. By displaying your `api_secret` here, your account is vulnerable to abuses. You should go to your account's settings page and create a new pair of api key+secret as soon as possible

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert the Uri into a string, I am doing the following in my upload code:

```
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(profileImageUri);
CloudinaryClient.upload(in, profileImageName);
```

CloudinaryClient:

```
public static void upload(final InputStream inputStream, final String publicId) {

    final Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("public_id", publicId);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                cloudinary.uploader().upload(inputStream, options);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //TODO: better error handling when image uploading fails
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Note: you can pass null as options, I just use it to specifiy a name for the image I am uploading.

Comment: is it required to extend  AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> and override (doInBackground) method to upload the pic ??

Comment: I've updated my code, I am using a runnable because I have no feedback for the user.

Comment: It throws `Unable to resolve host "api.cloudinary.com": No address associated with hostname` exception. Any idea?